# Basic question regarding order of dx, dy and dz

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

So, the question I am asking is so fundamental (and might be very obvious) that I could not find any previous  question similar to this particular question, which is this:
given a function $f(x,y,z)$ , we need to calculate its triple integral, so is it always necessary  that we start off by $$\int\int\int f(x,y,z)dxdydz  \tag{1}$$ and then change order of integral to calculate
(suppose:$\int\int\int f(x,y,z)dzdxdy [2]$) or we can directly start from $[2]$ given we know its appropriate upper limits and lower limits.

P.S.: I am not asking how to change order of $dx$, $dy$, $dz$ just asking if we can start by any arbitrary permutation of them.

Comment: Cf. [Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem)

Comment: The order of integration for a triple integral  does not depend on which letters you use.  For example, a volume calculation order depends essentially on ease of evaluation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you are careful to change the limits of integration appropriately, yes.

The easiest case is where the limits of integration are constants.  $\int_a^b\int_c^d\int_e^f F(x,y,z)dxdydz$ can be written in all 3!= 6 permutations and give the same result.  Its even simpler if F(x,y,z)= f(x)g(y)h(z): $\int_a^b\int_c^d\int_e^f F(x,y,z)dxdydz= \left(\int_a^b f(x)dx\right)\left(\int_c^d g(y)dy\right)\left(\int_e^f h(z)dz\right)$ and of course those three quantities can be permuted at will since multiplication of numbers is commutative.

If the limits of integration contain variables, it a little harder.  Suppose the integral is $\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^{\sqrt{1-y}} F(x,y,z)dxdydz= \int_0^1\int_0^{1-x^2}\int_0^1 F(x,y,z)dzdydx$.